# Navigating with window.location.hash multiple parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm developing some single page features and I'm using `window.location.hash` to rebuild the page after a refresh.

Basically I have a simple menu like this:

```
<a href = "#user">User</a>
<a href = "#comment">Comment List</a>
```

When pressing on the *Comment List* link the Browser URL will become:

```
myapp.com/#comment
```

On this page there are *Remove* links which call some AJAX function to remove the comment:

```
<a href = "#remove" class = "rmv-comment" data-id = "${commentId}">Remove Comment</a>
```

When pressing the *Remove Comment* link the Browser URL will become:

```
myapp.com/#remove
```

This is not very helpful because now I cannot rebuild the old page on a refresh. (The `#comment` hash isn't present therefore some default page will be displayed)

I'm looking for a way to build an URL like:

```
myapp.com/#comment/#remove
```

I tried appending different characters (like `\` or `?`) to `#comment` but no luck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you can only use **one** hash symbol

Instead of `myapp.com/#comment/#remove` you can use something like this:

```
myapp.com/comment/remove
```

To change the url without reloading the page use `window.history` object:

```
window.history.pushState("", "Title", "/remove");
window.history.pushState("", "Title", "/comment/remove");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! From what I understand, this would mean that I have to attach a JS function to every link right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Your server can process urls (like routing). So if you don't need to change urls on some pages then you don't have to use javascript on them

Comment: You can create only just one page and javascript will process the url